# Excel creating new Word document using template: Run-time error 5981. Method 'Add' of object 'Documents' failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error, excel-2016

I'm getting this error message: "Run-time error 5981. Method 'Add' of object 'Documents' failed."  This happens when I'm creating a new Word document using a template. The code is posted below and worked fine until the second user in the 2016 version started to use it.  It works fine for all 2013 users that are using the older version of the Word template.  The error shows up when it gets to the Set wdDoc = wdApp... line below.

```
Public wdDoc As Word.Document
QuoteDirectory = "R:\PartsQuotes\"
QuoteTemplate = "QuoteTemplate.dot" 'template used for 2013 users
If Application.Version = "16.0" Then QuoteTemplate = QuoteTemplate2016.dotx"
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Create an instance of word
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(QuoteDirectory & QuoteTemplate) 'Open word file
wdApp.Visible = True
```

I need to do a bunch more things with the Word document after it is created which is why I need to create it as a Word.Document. I can get around the error message by creating a second template for the second 2016 user. However, it would be much better to have a common shared template for all users.

Comment: tried .Open to open the template

Comment: Try changing this: QuoteTemplate2016.dotx" to "QuoteTemplate2016.dotx"

Comment: I'll try the .Open to open the template tonight when I get to my machine at home with 2016. Thanks @Nathan_Sav

Comment: I'm not sure how the first " character got dropped but the code in the file is already "QuoteTemplate2016.dotx".  Thanks for the suggestion @RyanWildry

Comment: Did you check the information related to this error code in this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/247028 ?

Comment: I have started interacting for questions pertaining to Excel-2016 from today only, I have simulated your program run on home network computer using Excel 2016 version with different users. I followed the following steps. First I downloaded Sales_quotes .dot templaate from internet and saved it as .dotx template. I put my code in a separate word macro enabled file. Made minor changes. Wrapped your code in Sub End Sub. changed your line `Public wdDoc As Word.Document to Dim wdDoc As Word.Document.` Since Public is not permitted in a Sub. Then I ran the program, it worked fine a number of times.

Comment: I passed macro-program file to other users and also a copy of word template, there too program worked fine number of times. They have to only ensure that paths are correct as per program at their location otherwise they should change the paths accordingly. Regarding error 5981, it is one of the commonly occurring error and there are many reasons ascribed to it. I have uploaded to drop box zipped folder comprising of template file, program file, sales quotes word document files generated by users.[HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jun_2016/word_sales_quote.zip)

Comment: I checked out that article that @DirkVollmar suggested but it does not directly apply since I'm not using the global template.

Comment: I'm not crazy about the suggestion of @Nathan_Sav because it opens the template rather than creating a new file based on the template.  However, I'll make sure it is ready-only and I've got code ready to test with the users that were having problems.

Comment: @skkakkar - were your other users all on 2016 and were they sharing the same template from the same network location? Thanks for all your efforts on this.

Comment: Oh and the Public wdDoc line was in the Declarations section outside of the sub.  I reused code from a previous project where I needed the document to be public so I could pass it between subs.

Comment: I have  just got up  hence delay in responding.We have tested this on home network. Other users used the same template on Excel 2016. I have sent you the file so that you can test it under your setup but taking care of the points mentioned by me.

Comment: Your program routine is perfectly ok. I only followed a theme that I should use .dotx template file instead of .dot file as my internet search revealed that suggestions for overcoming error 5981 were varying a lot, for example corrupt template file, another instance of Word getting initiated etc, Somewhere during this exploration, I got the clue that it would be preferable to use .dotx template with Excel 2016. I would appreciate feedback of your progress on this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the help for templates, there is a section that describes how to add a template, then use the templates(1).openAsDocument...

Comment: Hope you could reach to some solution.

Comment: Hi Everyone. I ended up going with the .open suggestion of @Nathan_Sav.  I'm sorry I didn't post that right away - I should have. I was under the gun to get this done for my client so I just made sure that the templates are in read-only mode. I also used the suggestion of skkakkar to use a .dotx template for all users.  Thanks to both of you for your efforts on this. Again I apologize for not posting my final solution and my thanks to you.  Thanks also to Emiel and Slai for their recent posted solutions. I won't be able to test these out unless my client has issues with the current version.

Comment: Thanks also to @skkakkar for the .dotx suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

My own Excel application opens a Word template.

Error 5981 is provoked when calling this statement:

```
Set oTemplate = moWordApp.Documents.Add(template:=sTemplate, Visible:=True)
```

The error may also be triggered when opening an existing Word document:

```
moWordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=...
```

In my situation the cause of error 5981 was that the Word-template was not a trusted document.
When opening the Word-template manually, it was opened in **protected view**. When opening the template automatically via VBA this apparently results in an error 5981.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However, I won't be able to test it out unless my client has problems with the current program.

Comment: Hi Russ, I changed my answer because I found the real cause of the error since my last post.

Answer (score 0):

A lazier solution can be :

```
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdDoc = GetObject("R:\PartsQuotes\QuoteTemplate.dot", "Word.Application") 
wdDoc.Application.Visible = True
```

This will open a new document based on the template in the current Word instance or will open new Word application if none open.

Or to try the .dotx template first:

```
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
On Error Resume Next
Set wdDoc = GetObject("R:\PartsQuotes\QuoteTemplate2016.dotx", "Word.Application") 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    Set wdDoc = GetObject("R:\PartsQuotes\QuoteTemplate.dot", "Word.Application") 
End If
If not wdDoc Is Nothing Then wdDoc.Application.Visible = True
On Error GoTo 0 ' optional to reset the error handler
```

Also note that *x files can be opened starting with Office 2007 where `.Application.Version = "12.0"`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However, I won't be able to test it out unless my client has problems with the current program.